# How do I upload 500 gigs on my wallpaper site?

Tags: web-hosting, vps, shared-hosting, cloud-hosting, dedicated-hosting

I have a wallpaper site. I have around 500 gigs of wallpapers on my local computer. I want all of them to be uploaded on my site. I started uploading them on my site. But after uploading 40 gigs on the server, the hosting company tells me that there is a "Soft Limit" on the space. Initially they told me that it is unlimited because nobody uses that much space. Than I started searching on the internet and every hosting company has this "Soft Limit" of 40 gigs.They asked me to get a dedicated server. But it's way too costly for the site. I'm currently using host-gator.
I thought of using image hosting services but they are not reliable and they don't allow hot-linking.
What do I do? Has anyone faced this problem? Help me.

Comment: this is rather insane thing to do...

Comment: What are you implying? What is insane

Comment: how much is ok for you to pay for 500GBs of space?

Comment: Sorry but this type of question is dupe and considered off-topic due to recommendations in nature.

Comment: `"Soft Limit" of 40 gigs` - where does it state this? HostGator uses the vague term "Unmetered", rather than "Unlimited", when referring to storage. Often, the unadvertised restriction is "iNodes", ie. the number of files.

Comment: I had a chat with the customer support more than once. All of them used this term.

Answer (score 0):

No one hosting company (reliable) will give you 500GB of storage for $5. Imagine can you rent your computer with 500GB harddisk for 24 hour with Internet connection of 1GBPS?

For too much storage you should go with dedicated plan or cloud hosting, like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

The image hosting site will also not store such a kind of images, without ads. Sites like imgur and blogspot allowed to upload unlimited photos, but who know when they will delete images.

Stackexchange also use imgur API to upload images on their server, but imgur server is too slow compare to normal hosting service. While blogspot may delete your whole album without any notice, because they don't want to become image hosting site. Flickr may allowed you to upload 1TB of pictures, worth looking on it, I don't know much idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a big variety of hosting providers. But, I'd put you up the prices. It's not so hard to host anything, you only need $$ to make it happen.

What would I do?  - I'd put it on cloud.

Math is like this:

**LINUX VPS**

> Disk space: 1TB is around 400$
>
> CPU: 8 100$
>
> RAM: 12GB is around 150$
>
> Installations etc. are in most cases free.

In total that's **650$.** Per year.

So, to put it softly, basically you can host anything anywhere, you just need money to do it. There's no site in the world that will give you this amount of space for free.

Comment: Cheaper to use a dedicated server: https://www.leaseweb.com/dedicated-servers#DE or even https://robot.your-server.de/order/market# around 20-30 euro pm

Comment: yeah it is. I just putted up the example.

Answer (score 0):

You're surprised that a cheap server can't store 500GB?! If I check my average website, 99.9% of the times smaller than 500mb (a 1000 times less then you now want!).

You might want to reconsider your current actions, 500GB of is a HUGE amount. You might want to check if you can optimize the images (think of services like [Kraken.io](http://kraken.io)). This might save you a lot of data.
Do you have an image of each resolution? How about you only keep your largest version of a ratio (16:9), and resize for the user when requested(and *then* store it if you need to). Again, will save you a huge amount of data.

Also, are all of the 500Gig's of images worth my while? This will require some feedback, but if an image scores too low, remove it from your site.

Comment: I'm already using the max resolution image and it is being dynamically resized and shown to the user. 500GB is all unique images.